# Generar salida Postgres en columnas

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta en una base de datos Postgres en la que quiero obtener resultados en forma de tabla como sigue. Las variables 1, 2...n son los names de los sensores que son conocidos (de la lista en la query). Entonces, el resultado sería para cada fecha, establecer el valor del sensor cuyo name es variableN.

```
logtime     variable1      variable2        variable3
------------------------------------------------------
fecha1          valor11        valor12          valor13
----------------------------------------------------
fecha2          valor21        valor22          valor23
----------------------------------------------------
```

Para ello, he visto la función `crosstab`, pero la verdad es que no sé muy bien cómo utilizarla. Agradecería cualquier ayuda para generar dicha query:

```
select * from crosstab(
'SELECT sensorhistdatalog.valuedate as logtime, sensorhistdatalog.value as logvalue, sensor.name FROM public.sensor
INNER JOIN public.sensorhistdatalog
ON sensor.id = sensorhistdatalog.sensor_id
where sensorhistdatalog.valuedate between ''2017-03-06'' and ''2017-03-07''
and sensor.name in (''LHTES_ON','C_VELOCIDAD_V3_MAN','C_VELOCIDAD_V4_MAN','VELOCIDAD_V3','VELOCIDAD_V4','LHTES MODE','TEMP_COMF_W','TEMP_COMF_S',
'TO_EXT','TO_INT','TI_EXT','TI_INT','TEMP_PLATE_1','TEMP_PLATE_2','TEMP_PLATE_3','TEMP_PLATE_4','DUMPER_1','DUMPER_2','REF_V3','REF_V4'')
order by name, valuedate asc')
as (
logtime text,
logvalue text,
name text);
```

Las tablas que quiero cruzar son sensorhistdatalog y sensor donde sensorhistdatalog tiene varias columnas, pero utilizamos el sensor_id (que es la clave foránea del id de la tabla sensor), la fecha y el valor, básicamente. La tabla sensor, es simplemente la lista de sensores con su id, nombre y descipción.

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
ERROR: no existe la función crosstab(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown)
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la estructura de las tablas de donde obtener esa consulta?

Comment: Pues son 2 tablas sensorhistdatalog y sensor donde sensorhistdatalog tiene varias columnas, pero utilizamos el sensor_id (que es el id de la tabla sensor), la fecha y el valor básicamente. La tabla sensor, es simplemente la lista de sensores con su id, nombre y descipción

Comment: no crees que sería pertinente en la pregunta?

Comment: Sería bueno aclarar si lo que quieres es que, dependiendo del valor de `sensor.name`, ponga el valor de `logvalue` en una determinada columna, y si los posibles valores de name son conocidos o pueden ser cualquier valor

Comment: Vale, lo he añadido todo en la pregunta. Los sensor.name son conocidos y están en la lista de la propia query. Entonces, se quiere, por cada una de las fechas, poner el valor del sensor cuyo name es variableN. De esta manera en vez de tener una lista de los pares fecha-valor ordenados por el nombre de la variable, se vería en formato tabla

Comment: Hola José Luis. Realmente sería mejor que describieras formalmente las tablas implicadas, que proveas datos de ejemplos, y que, para esos datos, nos muestres el resultado deseado. Aunque bien pudiera ser que el uso de `crosstab` sea útil en este caso, tal vez hay mejores soluciones o mas simples. Pero sin que realmente proveas el contexto necesario, es difícil darte la mejor ayuda.

Comment: Y si pudieras explicar también la parte `and sensor.name in (...`. ¿Ese filtro está allí porque existen otros "sensor names" que no te interesan, que no quieres incluir en los resultados?

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación de POSTGRESQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html):

> In practice the SQL query should always specify ORDER BY 1,2 to ensure that the input rows are properly ordered, that is, values with the same row_name are brought together and correctly ordered within the row. Notice that crosstab itself does not pay any attention to the second column of the query result; it's just there to be ordered by, to control the order in which the third-column values appear across the page.

O sea:

> En la práctica, la consulta SQL **siempre debe especificar ORDER BY 1,2 para asegurarse de que las filas de entrada están ordenadas correctamente**, es decir, los valores con el mismo nombre de fila se agrupan y se ordenan correctamente dentro de la fila. Observe que la tabla de referencias cruzadas **no presta ninguna atención a la segunda columna del resultado de la consulta**; está allí sólo para ser ordenado por, para controlar el orden en el que los valores de la tercera columna aparecen en la página.

Lo cual quiere decir que tu `order by name, valuedate asc` no sirve de nada en una consulta con `crosstab`. Dicho de otro modo, **toda consulta con `crosstab` debe llevar un `ORDER BY 1,2`**  .

Entonces:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT 
        sensorhistdatalog.valuedate as logtime, 
        sensorhistdatalog.value as logvalue, 
        sensor.name 
    FROM public.sensor
    INNER JOIN public.sensorhistdatalog
        ON sensor.id = sensorhistdatalog.sensor_id
        WHERE 
        sensorhistdatalog.valuedate between ''2017-03-06'' and ''2017-03-07''
        AND sensor.name in 
        (''LHTES_ON','C_VELOCIDAD_V3_MAN','C_VELOCIDAD_V4_MAN','VELOCIDAD_V3',
          'VELOCIDAD_V4','LHTES MODE','TEMP_COMF_W','TEMP_COMF_S',
          'TO_EXT','TO_INT','TI_EXT','TI_INT','TEMP_PLATE_1','TEMP_PLATE_2',
          'TEMP_PLATE_3','TEMP_PLATE_4','DUMPER_1','DUMPER_2','REF_V3','REF_V4'')
    ORDER BY 1, 2')
    AS (logtime text,logvalue text,name text);
```

Debería funcionar... a condición de que tu `SELECT`dentro de `crosstab` con su `JOIN` y su `WHERE` sea **correcto**, eso ya depende de ti.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque me sale un error que dice:      ERROR:  no existe la función crosstab(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown)

Comment: @JoseLuisHernandez Al parecer crosstab es una extensión que debe ser instalada. Para verificar si lo está puedes ejecutar esta consulta en PostgreSQL: `select count(*) from information_schema.routines where routine_name like 'crosstab%'
` si te retorna un `0`significa que no está instalada en tu BD, si retorna valores puede ser un error en tu consulta propiamente.

Comment: Para instalar crosstab tienes que ejecutar `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;`